# (Flutter, Vue, Springboot) Which options(about charset) can affected to mobile page

Tags: ios, flutter, vue.js, character-encoding, charset

I'm working on an IOS deployment.

My project is consist of flutter, vue, spring boot and all of system is setting as UTF-8. But I get a reply of about text error reject message again. And this is not occurred in our test device and virtual device.

So I'm checking again if there are additional options that need setting about text. Also when I build in Xcode, text option is UTF-8.

I got the same reject message before(same capture, same problem) and I thought I resolved it by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` code in all of vue page, because no more request about text error problem after editting until yesterday.
But I got this reject message today. What I editted is only Podfile, but I don't think the Podfile cause a error.

As a result, I want to ask

1. Addtional text setting is needed? 
   I setting below. 
   (1) When I build in Xcode -> UTF-8 setting 
   (2) In flutter -> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` code is included in `info.plist` directory under ios 
   (3) In vue -> `<meta charset="UTF-8">` I added the code above, every vue page 
   (4) In spring boot -> `<meta charset="UTF-8">` included in index.html page plus charset is written at applicaion.yml page
2. What happen if I don't setting a html lang like `<html lang="">` this code. If I doesn't specify the lang preperties(code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By editting the springboot settings, I can resolved the problem.
In application.yml file add below
server.servlet.encoding.force = true

and delete the code below
server.servlet.encoding.enabled = true

[note]
Force option: Whether to force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
Enable option: Whether to enable http encoding support.

Else I already setting below
(1) vue -> add the utf-8 code in all vue page
(2) spring boot -> edit the .yml file and index.html file(you need to add utf-8 code in index file)
(3) flutter -> check Info.plist and add the utf-8 code
(4) nginx -> make sure `charset utf-8` code included in nginx.conf file
(5) tomcat
(6) build text type -> In Xcode you can change text type of build

Basically all of files must be unified into the same type. (For example utf-8, ANSI, EUC-KR etc..)